# setup postfix SMTP on amazon ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, telnet, postfix-mta

Im trying to setup a postfix SMTP mail server on my amazon ec2 instance. i followed this guide http://cybart.com/how-to-install-and-configure-postfix-on-amazon-ec2/ and many other ones on configuring the main.cf

everytime i try to telnet my mail server mail.domain.com smtp it trys to connect to address XXX.XXX.XXX.XX but then operation is timed out and im unable to connect to remote host.

Comment: Can't help with the install problem, but generally speaking, its a pretty bad idea to run your own SMTP server on an EC2 instance. You may very well find that the IP you are running on has been previously blacklisted and your deliveryability rates may be quite under par. Consider using SES if you can.

Comment: ok lets assume im using SES what about receiving emails? Do i need to use imap/pop?

Comment: Can't recommend any software to install for that - I generally sub that out to someone like rackspace/microsoft/google and let them manage mailboxes for me. Personally have no interest in running a mail server - that can eat up a lot of your time to do it right.

Comment: Also, btw, amazon does now offer amazon workmail for pop3 mailboxes. http://aws.amazon.com/workmail/

Answer (score 6):

If you're still looking for guidance on how to setup an email server using Amazon EC2, I've written a guide for it. Even though some find using ec2 for email to be a hassle it doesn't have to be for you.

https://avix.co/blog/server-hosting

Here are some details about what the configuration will give you;

The system uses:

-Postfix as the smtp agent

-Dovecot as the client-side connect and mailbox manager

-Postgresql database to handle mail users, mail transports and the Spamassassin database

-Amavis (w/ Clamav & Spamassassin) for protection against viruses sent through email, and to facilitate an adaptive spam detection system that learns and corrects its behavior for each individual user

-Spamassassin as the spam filter and bayes to learn spam from ham and ham from spam

-Apache as the web setup, enables http & https connections to your site

-Squirrelmail as the default webmail. After the server is setup you will be able to check your email on yourdomain.com/mail from any browser on any device

The system supports:

-Multiple transports for different domain

Good luck, and let me know if I can clarify anything.

Comment: Sadly the link no longer works

Comment: https://github.com/Avix101/Mail-Server-Script is where his scripts are.  The support links are dead and aren't in archive.org.